# Node.js forwarding from local network to public Internet

Tags: internet, forwarding, node.js

I have a Server running node.js in my network that is not reachable via the internet (i.e., no static IP / domain).
However, I have a vServer with a domain that is running node.js as well. Can I forward data from the local server to the public domain? If so, what is the best practice in doing this?

First thing that came to my mind was using websockets on both the local machine and the public machine and forward new data (local->public vserver). Is that a feasible solution or are there better options?

Comment: What do you need exactly, either to make the node.js server in the private network to be accessible from the Internet, or to implement communication between those two node.js instances?

Comment: Implement communication. That is, sending data from my private network to the publicly accessible server and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only Node.js servers involved standard **[net](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html)** module should be sufficient.

The instance that is on public domain creates a socket and listen for incoming connections.  And then another one, located at the private network, may establish a connection to it.

WebSocket implementation could also be used, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392260/which-websocket-library-to-use-with-node-js for more information. Additional details is required to tell which would be more appropriate for your needs.